# Why all records from my sql table are getting deleted?

Tags: java, sql, database, jframe

I have a Java project to make for school. I work with sql and JFrame and I have a 3 tables(customers, orders, cars)  when I try to delete from orders (or edit) a record all records from orders are getting deleted instead of one. I'm guessing I have a problem with my sql query. 
So if anyone can tell me my mistake it would be great. :)

Here's my code:

```
class DeleteOrder implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        conn = DBConnector.getConnected();

        String selectCustomerId = "select cus_id from customers where lname=? and ";
           String selectCarId = "select car_id from cars where model=?";

           String selectedCustomer = customersCombo.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String selectedCar = carsCombo.getSelectedItem().toString();

        String sql="delete from Orders where " + selectCustomerId + selectCarId;

        try {
            state = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            state.setString(1, selectedCustomer);
            state.setString(2, selectedCar);
            state.execute();
            getAllDataFromOrders();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }

}//end Delete ORder
```

Comment: I'd expect it to look something like this: `sql="delete from Orders where cus_id = " + selectCustomerId + "AND car_id = " +selectCarId;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just adding two numbers and i really don't know why. I think instead of:

`String sql="delete from Orders where " + selectCustomerId + selectCarId;`

you should write:

`String sql="delete from Orders where cus_id =" + selectCustomerId +" and car_id = "+ selectCarId;`